# Visual studio form layout tutorial?

Tags: visual-studio, forms, layout

I'm a Qt developer, trying to design forms with visual studio.. but the layout toosl are.. lacking? I only see tools for fixed-size forms.

What are the visual studio alternatives to Qt's vertical/horizontal/grid layouts with minimum/maximum/preferred size hints, spacers, etc?? I can't see anything like this.

Comment: Winforms or ASP.NET Webforms?

Comment: …or WPF? WPF has the richest UI layout capability, but is fundamentally different than Windows Forms.

Comment: Winforms. I am targeting .Net 2.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closes things you can use are:

[FlowLayoutPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.flowlayoutpanel.aspx)

[TableLayoutPanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tablelayoutpanel.aspx)

Alternatively, you can go for WPF instead of WinForms.

Comment: You also have the `Dock` and `Anchor` properties for each control. They can be used in conjunction with the `FlowLayoutPanel` and `TableLayoutPanel` container controls, or independently. See [this guide](http://www.devx.com/dotnet/Article/6964/1954) for more details and sample design/code.